# Ada : invalid prefix in selected component

Tags: generics, filter, compiler-errors, tree, ada

I am developping a genereic program which filters data with Ada.
I tried to do that with a list and with a tree.

The program with lists implementation works perfectly.
My probleme is with the tree.

I have different generic packages :

**Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_g.ads**

```
generic
   TYPE Element IS PRIVATE;
   WITH FUNCTION "="(E1,E2 : IN Element) RETURN Boolean;
   WITH FUNCTION "<"(E1,E2 : IN Element) RETURN Boolean;
   WITH PROCEDURE Liberer_Element(E : IN OUT Element);
   WITH FUNCTION Element_To_String(E : IN Element) RETURN String;

package Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_g is

[...]

with function critere(E : in element) return Boolean;
 procedure Filtrer(A : in Arbre; B : out Arbre);
private
    TYPE Noeud;

  TYPE Arbre IS ACCESS Noeud;

  TYPE Noeud IS RECORD
     Info : Element;
     Gauche : Arbre;
     Droite : Arbre;
  END RECORD;

END Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_g;
```

This is the filter procedure, with the generic function critere :

**Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_g.adb**

```
 procedure Filtrer(A : in Arbre ; B : out Arbre) is
  begin
 if not Est_Vide(A) then
    Filtrer(A.Gauche, B);
    if critere(A.all.Info) then
       Inserer_element(B, A.all.info);
    end if;
    Filtrer(A.Droite, B);
 end if;
  end Filtrer;
```

**abr_acteurs.ads**

```
WITH Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G, Acteurs;  
USE Acteurs;


package ABR_acteurs is new Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G(acteur,"=","<",Liberer_acteur,Acteur_To_String);
```

*There are also **acteurs.ads** and **acteurs.adb** but it's not important here.*

And then, the client : **Tester_ABR_Acteur** :

```
WITH ABR_Acteurs, Acteurs, Ada.Text_Io, Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G;
use Ada.Text_Io, Abr_Acteurs;


PROCEDURE Tester_ABR_Acteurs is

 function Filtrage (Act : Acteurs.Acteur) return Boolean is
 begin
    return true;
 end Filtrage;

 procedure Filtrer_acteur is new Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G.Filtrer(Filtrage);
[...]
```

But, at compilation, there is the error : 
    **invalid prefix in selected component "Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G"**
At line :

```
procedure Filtrer_acteur is new Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G.Filtrer(Filtrage);
```

In client file.

---

There is the error, if I do this instanciation. 
But if I put my generic critere function with an other generic procedure / function, like this :

**Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_g.ads**

```
generic
   TYPE Element IS PRIVATE;
   WITH FUNCTION "="(E1,E2 : IN Element) RETURN Boolean;
   WITH FUNCTION "<"(E1,E2 : IN Element) RETURN Boolean;
   WITH PROCEDURE Liberer_Element(E : IN OUT Element);
   WITH FUNCTION Element_To_String(E : IN Element) RETURN String;
   with function critere(E : in element) return Boolean;
```

Then I instantiate like this :

**abr_acteurs.ads**

```
package ABR_acteurs is new Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G(acteur,"=","<",Liberer_acteur,Acteur_To_String, Critere_acteur);
```

There is no error, and everything works correctly!

I can't find out where the problem is !

================================================================
I do exactly the same with my list implementation, with generic function at the end of my generic package, and it works correctly! I don't understand..

Does anyone have an idea?

[**Update**]

- My generic function : **with function critere(E : in element) return Boolean;** is in the procedure : **procedure Filtrer(A : in Arbre; B : out Arbre);**, like that :

  ```
  procedure Filtrer(A : in Arbre ; B : out Arbre) is  
     begin  
   if not Est_Vide(A) then  
      Filtrer_hihi(A.Gauche, B);
  ```

***Here there is critere(A.all.Info)***

```
        if critere(A.all.Info) then  
           Inserer_element(B, A.all.info);  
        end if;  
        Filtrer_hihi(A.Droite, B);  
     end if;  
      end Filtrer;
```

So, it's normal if I instantiated my procedure in this way, because (Refer to 2.)

- That's how I proceeded with my generic list :

package **liste_ordonnee_g.ads**

```
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;

generic
   type Element is private;
   with function "<"(E1, E2 : in Element) return Boolean;
   with function "="(E1, E2 : in Element) return Boolean;
   with procedure Liberer_Element(E : in out Element);
   with function Element_To_String(E : in Element) return String;

package Liste_Ordonnee_G is

    type Liste is private;

 [...]

generic
    with function Critere(E:Element) return Boolean;

function Filtrer(L : Liste) return Liste;

private

type Cellule;
type Lien is access Cellule;
type Cellule is record
    Info : Element;
    Suiv : Lien;
end record;

type Liste is record
    Debut : Lien;
    Cardinal : Natural;
end record;

-- procedure de liberation de la memoire occupee par la cellule
procedure Liberer_Cellule is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(Cellule, Lien);

end Liste_Ordonnee_G;
```

**liste_ordonnee_g.adb**

```
function Filtrer(L : Liste) return Liste is
   New_Liste : Liste;
   Aux :Lien ;
begin
   Creer_Liste(New_Liste);
   Aux := L.Debut;
   while Aux /= null loop
```

***Here there is critere(A.all.Info)***

```
      if Critere(Aux.all.Info) then
     Inserer(Aux.all.Info, New_Liste);
      end if;
      Aux := Aux.all.Suiv;
   end loop;
   return New_Liste;
end Filtrer;
```

Here, I instantiate my generic package WITHOUT the function critere :

**liste_ordonnee_acteurs.ads**

```
with Acteurs, Liste_Ordonnee_G;
use Acteurs;

PACKAGE Liste_Ordonnee_Acteurs IS new Liste_Ordonnee_G(Acteur, "<", "=", Liberer_Acteur, Acteur_To_String);
```

And in my client file : I instanciate my generic procedure **filtrer** with the **critere** :

**Test_Liste_Ordonnee_Acteurs.adb**

```
 function Filtrage (A : Acteurs.Acteur) return Boolean is
   begin
      return Acteurs.Annee(A) = 2000;
   end Filtrage;

   function Filtrer is new Liste_Ordonnee_Acteurs.filtrer(Filtrage);
```

List implementation works correctly! I don't understand why tree implementation doesn't work :( ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the list version, you have

```
with Acteurs, Liste_Ordonnee_G;
use Acteurs;
PACKAGE Liste_Ordonnee_Acteurs
   IS new Liste_Ordonnee_G(Acteur, "<", "=", Liberer_Acteur, Acteur_To_String);
```

which results (effectively) in a new generic function `Liste_Ordonnee_Acteurs.Filtrer` like

```
generic
   with function Critere(E:Acteur) return Boolean;
function Filtrer(L : Liste) return Liste;
```

which you instantiate successfully as

```
function Filtrage (A : Acteurs.Acteur) return Boolean is
begin
   return Acteurs.Annee(A) = 2000;
end Filtrage;

function Filtrer is new Liste_Ordonnee_Acteurs.filtrer(Filtrage);
```

What you've done in the tree version is the equivalent of

```
function Filtrer is new Liste_Ordonnee_G.filtrer(Filtrage);
```

so you need to change

```
procedure Filtrer_acteur is new Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G.Filtrer(Filtrage);
```

to

```
procedure Filtrer_acteur is new ABR_Acteurs.Filtrer(Filtrage);
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you!

Of course that was it! Sometimes, I can be very stupid !

Thank you again ;-)!!

Answer (score 2):

`Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G` is the name of your generic package.  A generic package is not a package; it's a template from which you can create a package by instantiating it (defining an instance).

And `Filtrer` is a non-generic procedure declared in the generic package.

When you write:

```
procedure Filtrer_acteur is new Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G.Filtrer(Filtrage);
```

you're trying to refer to the `.Filtrer` name from something that's not a package -- and `Filtrer` itself isn't even a generic.

If you instantiate your `Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G` package, you can then refer to the `Filtrer` function defined in that instance (which is a package):

```
package Actual_Package is new Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G(...);
...
... Actual_Package.Filtrer ...
```

(But from within a generic package, the name of the generic package refers to the current instance, not to the generic, so `Arbre_Binaire_Recherche_G.Filtrer` is a valid procedure name *in that context*. I'm not sure whether that's relevant to your problem.)

Comment: I think he already has an `Actual_Package`, namely `ABR_acteurs`.  That's what he should use.  (Also, I think `Filtrer` may actually be a generic procedure, because of the `with function` just before it; the keyword `generic` is probably hiding in the `[...]`.)